# Compare xml tag with textbox

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8

I want read my xml and if the text in textbox is the same as the tag in xml i want it to navigate to other page.

my code is :

```
     StorageFolder storageFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Registeduser.xml");

        string xml = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        StorageFolder pastaxml = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        pastaxml = await pastaxml.GetFolderAsync("users\\1101046102\\xml\\");
        StorageFile login = await pastaxml.GetFileAsync("info.xml");

        string xmllogin = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(login, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);

        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmllogin);

        var rootemail = xdoc.Root;

        var rootNode = doc.Root;
        foreach (var child in rootNode.Descendants("user"))
        {
            //Login is a class
            var objLogin = new Login
            {
                id = child.Element("id").Value,
                Email=child.Element("email").Value
            };
        }
        foreach (var logemail in rootemail.Descendants("info"))
        {
            //Info is a class
            var email = new Info
            {
               Email = logemail.Element("email").Value
            };
            Info info = new Info();

            if (txtemail.Text == info.Email.ToString())
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DashBoard));
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox("Email ou password incorreta");
            }
        }
```

and the xml is:

```
    <info>
        <id>1101046102</id>
       <email>email@hotmail.com</email>
    </info>
```

and:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <registeredUser>
      <user>
        <id>1101046102</id>
        <email>email@hotmail.com</email>
      </user>
   </registeredUser>
```

All i want is compare the email in registeduser.xml with the email in info.xml. When i debud the program and click to go next page, the program dont do anything. 
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: If you share your XAML code and your full code behind, we may be able to help you, also, are you aware you can put breakpoints in your code, are you?

Answer (score 0):

> All i want is compare the email in registeduser.xml with the email in info.xml

```
bool isEqual = doc.Descendants("email").First().Value == 
               xdoc.Descendants("email").First().Value;
```